# Limit serverside results from WebApi controller and ODATA w/ Nhibernate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, nhibernate, asp.net-web-api, odata

I've created a WebApi project in VS 2012, using NHibernate as my ORM and I intend to enable Odata support on it. So I've created a test controller with a single Get method that returns a list of entities from a table on my database.

Everything works fine, I can use OData to filter and order my results, etc. The problem is I couldn't find a way to limit the amount of data that's being returned from the database to the controller, and this table has millions of records in it.

Using the `PageSize` property of the `Queryable` attribute only seems to be limiting the amount of data returned to the client, but no the amount of Data returned from the DB.

I've tried applying a `Take(n)` on the `IQueryable` inside the get method before returning it, and it limits the results brought back from the DB, but it breaks the OData filtering, since if you try to query an entity that's not in the first n results, it just returns an empty collection.

I know you can use the `$Top` parameter on OData to accomplish this, but I would like not to depend on the client/consumer providing it in order to ensure that I'm not unnecessarily bringing thousands or even million of records that I'm not going to use.

I've also tried to manually check if the client provided a Top parameter on the query string, apply the OData transformation to my Queryable and then applying the `Take(n)` method over the transformed query. This approach enabled me to filter for any entity through OData, but it breaks pagination, because if I use the `$Skip=n` parameter, it again returns an empty collection.

So, is there any way to reliably limit the results fetched from the DB while not breaking the OData support?

Comment: What are you using as a bridge between OData and NHibernate? Are you hand rolling it converting OData into an NHibernate IQueryable or are you using a library? Also, in the past I've seen people automatically impose a TOP 1000 on all results returned over an API and send some information indicating that they've only received part of the requested data and often providing a pre-created URL that the caller can use that will return the next 1000 results. The caller would continue to use the provided URLs until they have received all of the data.

Comment: I'm not using OData to create the queries directy but rather as a convenience tool for my client to filter the returned results from the existing methods. So for example i have a GetAllProducts() methods, which performs a querie using Linq to NHibernate, and i return that IQueryable. The behaviour you describe is the default behaviour when using the PageSize property on Queryable atribute, but as i mention in my post this only limits what the client recives, but not the results that are fetched from the DB to my service method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We recently found that too. We are not applying a Take(pageSize) when server driven paging is enabled as we have to figure out if a next page link should be generated or not. We just enumerate the result set for pageSize number of entities and check if there are more entities or not. We thought that most providers generally bring a partial set of results as IQueryable is generally a lazy implementation. Turns out that is not true. Also, the database can optimize the query if it knows only pageSize number of results are required.

[This](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/901) is the issue that was opened for it. Good news is Youssef fixed it already :). This is the [commit](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/8517d73f5f60ffb3e1c8a590af4695c7bda37709) that fixed it. So, if you grab the nightly builds you should be good.

Comment: I saw that issue yesterday, but if you click the link to the fix, the page is missing, which gives me a bad hunch. I'll try to get an up to date build and test this to see this.

Comment: Looks like codeplex doesn't understand partial sha1 anymore. Anyways, this link should work https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/8517d73f5f60ffb3e1c8a590af4695c7bda37709